# Correct way to reference log4net DLL in WinForms application

Tags: c#, log4net

My WinForms 2.0 application has 2 assemblies. 1st assembly handles GUI and project specific code, and 2nd assembly is where I put all my reusable code. Both projects are part of the solution; 1st project references the 2nd project.

Now both the projects need to reference the log4net.dll file. Should I add a reference in each project pointing to the folder where I have downloaded log4net source code and built it; or should I copy the log4net.dll file into each project directory?

Or should I also add the entire log4net source code project as part of the solution, so that I am insulated from any future changes in log4net breaking my existing application?

One of the requirement is that future version changes in log4net which have potential risk of breaking existing code, should have minimum impact on my projects.

What is the best practice?

I am using C# 2.0.

Thanks,

Comment: why would future version changes in log4net affect your project if you don't change the dll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> should I copy the log4net.dll file into each project directory?

No. Keep it at separate dependencies folder. This folder should be common for all projects in Solution. You should reference log4net.dll into each  project (that require this component).

> Or should I also add the entire log4net source code project as part of the solution, so that I am insulated from any future changes in log4net breaking my existing application?

It is not required. It is required **only if** you are facing any issues in log4net.dll and want to diagnose yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I usually build the project and put the log4net dll in a libs folder which is a solution folder. Both projects reference this dll (libs folder).

Comment: Hmm...and I presume I also need to put the log4net.xml file in this solution folder? Sorry, this may be a basic question, but I am just getting started with log4net. Also I have never used solution folder before. I just created one now, but it does not seem to create any folder in the filesystem. Then, instead of this, I might as well create a folder in the hard disk, put the log4net files there, and reference them in both projects?

Comment: You don't need the XML doc file but you can put it there. Create the folder on disk and as a solution folder.

Comment: Sorry again, but if I have to create a folder on disk anyway, why do I need to create a solution folder? From what I have read in other threads, the solution folder and the physical folder do not synchronize; what is it that I can not achieve with physical folder, which I can achieve only through solution folder?

Comment: You don't have to, but I prefer to see all data in VS

Comment: I still don't get the point ... Even by having only a physical folder, I can add that folder in VS, right?

Comment: Yes as a solution folder. There is nothing special about it

Comment: Well, I used a common physical folder; not the solution folder. I could not see any advantages of a solution folder here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Learn to rely on NuGet, it will automatically manage your dependencies and store them in proper folder.

As for log4net, the compatibility has already been broken because of messed keys and broken method contracts. No one knows how to resolve this mess:

http://netpl.blogspot.com/2012/03/pathetic-breaking-change-between.html