# Best Practice for common log4net configuration file for multiple projects in a WinForms solution and configurable logger names

Tags: c#, log4net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Correct way to reference log4net DLL in WinForms application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14112559/correct-way-to-reference-log4net-dll-in-winforms-application)

My WinForms solution has 2 projects: 1 for project specific code, the other for reusable code. I am referencing log4net.dll from both projects. I have kept the dll in a libs folder under the main solution folder, and referencing this DLL from both projects. Note: This is a physical folder, not a solution folder.

I want to specify the log4net configuration settings in a single xml file which can be read by both projects.

1. Where do I keep this xml file?
2. How to point log4net XmlConfigurator to read from this xml file?
3. If I do not want to hardcode the xml file name and path, what are the options?
4. (Optional Question) Suppose I do not want to follow the convention of using the fully qualified class name as the logger name; rather at run time I want to read the logger name for each class from an xml file (the objective is to isolate the parent-child logger relationships in an external file and to decide later); then what are the options?

I am using C# 2.0.

Although these sound like lot of questions, they should be simple for seasoned log4net developers, I guess!

EDIT 1: I do not want to mix log4net config in app.config file itself.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you opening duplicate question? You can edit your original question itself.

Comment: The other question was related to DLL file referencing, this question is related to XML file and has a different purpose altogether, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I found the solution.

1. I am now keeping the XML file in the project folder of the Project which is marked as Startup Project. In the File properties in Project, I have set "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy if newer"
2. I am pointing log4net XmlConfiguration to this XML file using assembly level attribute:

   [assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile="LogConfig.xml",Watch = true)]
3. Currently I have hardcoded the file name in the above attribute. If later I do not want to hardcode, I can insert a log4net.Config key in the appSettings section in the app.config file.
4. If I want to read the logger name for each class from an xml file, I can insert appropriate keys for each fully qualified class name in app.config file, and read from there.

If anyone has alternate ideas, please post.